# UFT: Working with Excel file that is already opened

Tags: vbscript, automation, qtp, hp-uft

I have an Excel file that is already opened and the name of Excel file is generated randomly.I need to update the fields in the Excel and save this at some location but I am not able to get the handler for this Excel file.

Tried using `getObject` method available in UFT but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Since you included vbscript as a tag, here is the code to do it in vbscript. Save it in a text file with "vbs" extension and you can run it.

```
Dim objXL

On Error Resume Next

Set objXl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Not TypeName(objXL) = "Empty" then
    MsgBox objXL.Workbooks(1).path, vbInformation, "Excel Status"
    MsgBox objXL.Workbooks(1).name, vbInformation, "Excel Status"
    MsgBox objXL.Workbooks(1).fullname, vbInformation, "Excel Status"
Else 
    MsgBox "Excel NOT Running", vbInformation, "Excel Status"
End If
```